# Ruamel yaml formatting of dumped nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I would like to dump a dictionary with components that are nested lists, where each row of the list is on its own line. I also want to maintain dictionary order.

Here's a MWE:

```
import sys

from ruamel import yaml
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

d = {'b':1,
     'a':[[1, 2],[3, 4]]}

# desired output:
# b: 1
# a:
# - [1, 2]
# - [3, 4]

print()
yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout)
print('\n')
YAML().dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

And here's what I actually get:

```
a:
- [1, 2]
- [3, 4]
b: 1


b: 1
a:
- - 1
  - 2
- - 3
  - 4
```

The first method has the nested-list formatting I want, but loses dictionary order. (Not a surprise since I'm not using a round-trip dumper) The second method manages to maintain order, but loses my desired nested list formatting. Any time I use a round-trip dumper, I've lost the nice nested list formatting.

Any tips here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That your dictionary has the order you want is either luck, or because you are using Python 3.6. In older versions of Python (i.e < 3.6) this order is not guaranteed.

If you are only targeting 3.6 and have `ruamel.yaml>=0.15.32` you can do:

```
import sys

from ruamel import yaml
from ruamel.yaml import YAML


d = {'b':1,
     'a':[[1, 2],[3, 4]]}

y = YAML()
y.default_flow_style = None
y.dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

if you have an older version and Python 3.6:

```
import sys

from ruamel import yaml
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

y = YAML()

d = {'b':1,
     'a':[y.seq([1, 2]),y.seq([3, 4])]}


for seq in d['a']:
    seq.fa.set_flow_style()
y.dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

to get:

```
b: 1
a:
- [1, 2]
- [3, 4]
```

to get the order you want in older versions of Python consistently you should do:

```
d = y.map()
d['b'] = 1
d['a'] = y.seq([1, 2]),y.seq([3, 4])
```

and with `ruamel.yaml>=0.15.32` you can leave out the call to `y.seq()`.

Comment: What if the data is from a file constains many list format like [[1, 2], [3, 4]]?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking so it may be better to post a real question. When using the default, round-trip, parser each sequence (and mapping) is loaded into a structure that knows whether it was flow or block style. These will be dumped back as they were, of course withing the constraints of YAML if there has been heavy manipulation (i.e. you can never have a block style mapping/sequence within a flow style)